# Como obtener la lista de amigos de facebook con la API Grap desde android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, facebook

Estoy tratando de una ves que me login en facebook desde mi aplicacion en android poder obtener un listado de mis amigos ,asi como agunos datos , me estoy guiando por esto https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends pero a la hora de consultal el json que me devuelve me resulta que esta vacio , este es el codigo

```
public void amigos(String id){

  //  final String returnString="prueba " ;

    //final String canamigo="0";




    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/friends",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        /* handle the result */

                        String nombres="nombres: ";
                        String otro="nombres: ";
                    try {
                      JSONObject json_data=response.getJSONObject();
                        JSONArray frienArray = ((JSONArray) (response.getJSONObject().get("data")));

                        System.out.println("este es el jsom"+json_data);


                        //JSONArray aray=json_data.getJSONArray("data");

                        System.out.println("este es el array2"+frienArray.length());

                           if(frienArray!=null) {
                               System.out.println("no es nulo "+frienArray);
                               for (int i = 0; i < frienArray.length(); i++) {

                                   JSONObject amigo = frienArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                   System.out.println("nombre de la persona :-"+amigo.getString("first_name"));
                                   otro= amigo.getString("first_name");
                               }
                           }
                      TextView listaAmigos=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombres);

                      listaAmigos.setText(otro);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();

   TextView listaAmigos=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombres);

    listaAmigos.setText(id);

    Log.d(id, "onCompleted: esto es el id");




}
```

he intentado por varias vias pero nada,alguientiene alguna idea que me pueda ayudar. gracias de antemano

Comment: Me gustaria saber tambien si con la API Graph puedo obtener el listado de cumpleaños de mi usuario